# Scala get first element of ArrayBuffer which satisfies condition

Tags: scala

I have a `var` of type `ArrayBuffer`.

```
var selected = new ArrayBuffer[Component](0)
```

I would like to extract from it the first element which satisfies a given condition.

```
var res = selected.filter(_.node == neighbour)(0)
```

I want something like the line above, but in case no element satisfies that condition, I want `res` to be `null`. Instead, the code is throwing an error.

How can I get the first element satisfying the condition or `null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, use `find` instead of filter which will return the first one on an `Option`. Then use `orNull` to get the value or `null` if it is missing:

```
val res = selected.find(_.node == neighbour).orNull
```

Or you could use `filter`, `headOption`, and `orNull`

```
val res = selected.filter(_.node == neighbour).headOption.orNull
```

As a kind of mandatory note when dealing with `null`: Using `Option` instead of `null` is the scala idiomatic and recommended way.